# EMC Dispatcher Classification Edit 7.10 will not open batches

Tags: documentum, emc, captiva

After the user scan the document, those will show up on Captiva Administrator (v7.10) on "Error" Status, when trying to open those for Classification on the Classification Edit application it will keep idle with the message "Waiting for Task", also noticed the Priority is set as "Offline".

I tried to manually import a document and it went into "Normal" status and I was able to run the Classification Edit app for it, need help on what may be causing the scanned docs going into Error Status.

Note: Scanning is done on a laptop with an actual scanner device using a local ScanPlus installation.

Within the Documentum Export Module I can see this error:

> Cannot attach lifecycle policy to the object 46015da88304f7be,
> LifeState Open, LifeAlias  due to Documentum error:
> [DM_SESSION_E_LAUNCH_BP_TRANSITION]error:  "Unable to launch the BP
> transition evaluation process due to the error: Unknown
> errors".[CR][LF]

And whenever I disable the Lifecycle on the module settings the error will not occur.

[image]

**UPDATE**
After starting the JBOSS JMS the issue seems fixed, I've no a clear idea on how the communication from the Documentum Export Module with the JMS work (as we have 2 Content Servers but JMS was stopped only in 1 of them), but I'm aware that his particular process failing had a Life Cycle set on the Documentum Export module settings (Captiva) and that the JMS is responsible of assigning the Life Cycle to the Documents.

Comment: Looks like JMS service/process which are running on the Content Servers were stopped in 1 of them, after started them as per the script which was already in place issue seems fixed, still need to confirm with the user